# $\prod_{i}^n B_i \otimes_R \prod_{i}^n B_i = \prod_{i}^n (B_i \otimes_R B_i)$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A \to B$ a $R-$algebra. It's true that finite direct products are isomorphic to direct sums, then using the property for direct sums and tensor products, I've got
$$\prod_{i}^n B_i \otimes_R \prod_{i}^n B_i = \prod_{i}^n \prod_{j}^n(B_i \otimes_R B_j)$$
which seems ok, but it makes works with those expressions a little harder. So, there is some way to say that
$\prod_{i}^n B_i \otimes_R \prod_{i}^n B_i = \prod_{i}^n (B_i \otimes_R B_i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn’t work unless $R$ is the zero ring. If this were true, we’d have $(0 \times R) \otimes (R \times 0) \cong (0 \otimes R) \times (R \otimes 0) \cong 0$

But what we in fact get is $(0 \times R) \otimes (R \times 0) \cong R \otimes R \cong R$.

So this could only be valid if $R \cong 0$ as $R$-modules, which is true only if $R$ is the zero ring.